# GGTS dies while trying to debug a Grails project

Tags: grails, ggts

I am using Grails 2.4.3 with GGTS 3.6.2 on eclipse 4.4.0, on Windows 8.1 ...

When asked to debug using "debug as -> run-app" it just hangs after showing following ...

```
Loading Grails 2.4.3
Configuring classpath.
Environment set to development
.................................
Packaging Grails application
....................................
Running Grails application
```

Terminating the process gives the following:

```
Loading Grails 2.4.3
Configuring classpath.
Environment set to development
.................................
Packaging Grails application
....................................
Running Grails application
Error
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I am not able to debug anything at all.
The problem is same with Grails 2.4.4, GGTS 3.6.3/4, with Eclipse 4.4.1.

Comment: On a slightly related topic, please note that GGTS is going to be deprecated. Looks like for best support you should switch to Idea.

Comment: @Miguel Please provide more info about this. Where can we get official confirmation about this.

Comment: here: http://spring.io/tools/ggts let me quote: "Groovy/Grails Tool Suite™
will be available from Pivotal for a limited time"

Comment: In there anything in the grails or eclipse logs?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest remote debugging grails app from eclipse, it works the best.

In eclipse / ggts, create a debug configuration for a "remote java application" on port 5005

Run grails from grails console (command prompt) with following command

grails --debug-fork and then run-app

when it say waiting to connect on port 5005, run your remote debug configuration which you just created above. and you should be able to debug the application.